# How to fix mismatching type of object returned in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm developing and application using ruby2d.

I have a function that should return an object which class is "Tile".

The object that will be returned is "tileStone" and while it's inside the function, its class is "Tile" (I have used some "puts" for printing this information). But, when it returns for the main function, it returns as a "Ruby2D::Window::EventDescriptor" object. Why?

```
 def player1turn(grid)
      tileStone  = stoneChose(1,grid)
      puts tileStone.class #here it prints "Ruby2D::Window::EventDescriptor", which is wrong
  end

  def stoneChose(nplayer,grid)
    Window.on :mouse do |event|
      case event.button
      when :left
        grid.movableStone(grid.getPlayer(nplayer)).each do |tileStone|
          if tileStone.contains? event.x, event.y
            puts tileStone.class #here it prints "Tile"
            tileStone

          end 
        end 
      end
    end 
  end
```

Comment: For me it is not clear, what should be returned in `stoneChose`. Is it the first tileStone found? If so, then replace `tileStone` with `return tileStone`. I am not sure, but without exact return Ruby will return last object seen in the procedure

Comment: For the first comment: Yes. It will return the first tileStone found. I can't use "return tileStone" because ruby doesn't allow me (it says that it's an unexpected return), so I just ommited the "return".
For the second: why the events will happen a long time after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `ruby2d`, but it seems, that `Window.on` only puts an event listener/handler, and returns `EventDescriptor`. Next, when the event is fired, the code inside `on` will be executed. Thus, your function `stoneChose` just set this event listener and returns this descriptor class instance.

You can check a general architecture of `ruby2d` project in this [Pong game](https://github.com/tiagopog/pong/blob/master/pong.rb). In short words:

1) You have to setup all your event listeners first

```
def setup
    Window.on :mouse do |event|
        case event.button
        when :left
        grid.movableStone(grid.getPlayer(nplayer)).each do |tileStone|
            if tileStone.contains? event.x, event.y
                doSmthWithTileStone(tileStone)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

2) Define a function, which does some action with your found object on each event

```
def doSmthWithTileStone(tileStone)
    puts tileStone
end
```

3) And do the main app loop

```
def main
    setup

    update do
        ...
    end
end

main
```